# Elevation distribution of protected areas using QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, area

I am using QGIS.

Based on a DEM and a vector layer of polygons for protected areas in the Alps, I would like to calculate the areas of the respective protected area polygons in certain altitude classes (0-500m; 500-1000m;1000-1500m; etc.).

Is there a direct way of realizing such a calculation or do I need to convert the DEM to shapefiles according to the altitude classes and then clip/intereect those polygons (as described here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/202435/152823)?

So far I have tried to create contours and now I want to try to clip this shp with an overlay with my protected area polygons.

Comment: You do not even need to mask the DEM, just use a conditional statement for each elevation range to create new rasters with a value of 1. You can then use a zonal statistics function to sum each elevation range raster. This will give you the number of cells, in each given polygon, within that elevation range. Based on resolution of the DEM you can then easily get at area.

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey, I'll try to follow your instructions. Never did a zonal statistics, but sure there are guides somewhere...